# Error C7626: Unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members,

Tags: c++, visual-studio, error-handling

I am using C++ in VS2022 to build a project. I have to include a header file from an sdk named `eve.h`. I have added the include folder holding this file into the project properties.
However, when I build this project, I get a number of C7626 errors stating the following, and pointing to certain lines of the `eve.h` file.

```
Error   C7626   unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes (compiling source file main.cpp)
```

The code in one of the lines the error points to is this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int isOpen;

    int clearAll;
    int clearSome;
    int buttonFifty=-1;
    int buttonTwenty=-1;

}ALL_Buttons;
```

This is a header file in the sdk, it is not my code. And I have never come across this error before. How can I work this out? Thanks

Comment: Compiles fine [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Vaq6bia8c)

Comment: On Godbolt, compiles even with MSVC. However, your error is presented there as warning C5208: https://godbolt.org/z/MnhTenYEe.

Comment: _"...and Error C7626 ...To turn off the warning without code changes..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c5208?view=msvc-170

Comment: @DanielLangr live repo - https://godbolt.org/z/zqnYPxfz8

Comment: @DanielLangr But in my case, it's not a warning. It's an error. So, what are my options in that case?

Comment: @TreeBig remove `/permissive-` however this is not advisable as it put the MSVC compiler into non-conforming / extension mode. Or contact the library writers and get them to fix their code for C++ (it might be valid C not sure).

Comment: Try setting the `/permissive` option (in VS, turn "conformance mode" **on** in the "Properties -> Language" page).

Comment: @RichardCritten It's not valid C, as C doesn't have inline initialization of member variables. Which begs the question why the original authors used `typedef` to begin with.

Comment: @AdrianMole setting the `/permissive` option still doesn't help.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - thanks I don't know enough `C` to be sure.

Comment: This "SDK" is junk. Try to find a different SDK that's written to modern, proper C++ standards.

Comment: @TreeBig it should change the error into a warning - live with and without - https://godbolt.org/z/a8beK18nb

Comment: @TreeBig What is this SDK that you downloaded? Downloaded from where? SDK for what? Is it supposed to be a C SDK, or a C++ SDK? And this is really an issue that needs to be brought to the attention of the SDK maintainers or authors.

Comment: What is your [warning settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170)? Even with `/permissive`, warnings may be treated as errors: https://godbolt.org/z/r3edrK9G7. But then, adding `/wd5208` may help: https://godbolt.org/z/7Majdbd7j.

Comment: @DanielLangr warning level is 1

Comment: Regarding Error C7626, you could refer to the suggestions in this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c5208?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT This link has already been posted here, namely in the 3rd comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by giving the structures in the sdk names. As follows:

Before:

```
typedef struct
{
    int isOpen;

    int clearAll;
    int clearSome;
    int buttonFifty = -1;
    int buttonTwenty = -1;
}
```

After:

```
typedef struct a
{
    int isOpen;

    int clearAll;
    int clearSome;
    int buttonFifty = -1;
    int buttonTwenty = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As from Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c5208?view=msvc-170) your `struct` has no name but is inside a typedef with some members which are initializated in line.
The code below compile fine in VS 2022

```
typedef struct 
{
    int isOpen;

    int clearAll;
    int clearSome;
    int buttonFifty;// = -1;
    int buttonTwenty;// = -1;

}ALL_Buttons;
int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler emit a warning or an error depending on C++ version.